# Problem installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I'm new to Linux, but I hope you guys can help me. I'm installing it through USB and I get this error message:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to boot into Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes im able to boot in but the menu is diffrent and strange  , that should be the install files